return real[] array from postgres as full float values
I have a table in postgres which has a column with real[] entries.

I need to export these values as a text like this:
      CASE WHEN z > 16 THEN '{"cityJson" :' ||  cityjsonfeature::TEXT || ', "metadata" : {' || '"translate:"'||'{' ||   m.translate  ||'},'|| '"scale:"'||'{' ||   m.scale  ||'}' '}' ELSE NULL END AS cityjson,

the problem here is, that I do not get the full values, but instead it looks like this:
{98.016,1.3326125e+06,6.7176775e+06}
is there any way to get the values without the e+06 but instead as a full float value? like 1332612.5?
Thanks a lot for help!

If you're still interested in answers to your other question, make sure to respond to the comments.

@Zegarek i will responde, when i have figured more out! i am still struggeling on so many frontiers ;)

You can cast the real[] to float[]:
CASE WHEN z > 16 THEN concat('{"cityJson" :', cityjsonfeature::TEXT,
                             ', "metadata" : {', 
                             '"translate:"','{', m.translate::float[]::text,'},',
                             '"scale:"','{', m.scale ,'}')
                 ELSE NULL 
END AS cityjson,

And that's exactly what it will do: demo
select ('{98.016,1.3326125e+06,6.7176775e+06}'::real[])::float[];




float8




{98.01599884033203,1332612.5,6717677.5}



Note that the text representation of that array will not follow JSON array syntax. The { are for JSON objects, not arrays. You're also adding them on top of the curly braces that'll come with the textual representation which breaks things further. Your scale will also end up malformed, for the same reasons.
You also put the colon inside the key names "translate:" and "scale:", instead of after them "translate":, "scale":. You can avoid manual mistakes like that by using json_build_object() function instead of constructing it manually. It'll also reformat your PostgreSQL arrays into valid JSON arrays for you. You can also use the jsonb version to get access to jsonb_pretty(), if you need output formatted for human readability: demo
SELECT
CASE WHEN z > 16 
     THEN jsonb_pretty(
             jsonb_build_object( 
                 'cityJson',cityjsonfeature
                ,'metadata',jsonb_build_object( 
                                'translate',m.translate
                               ,'scale',m.scale )
              )
          )
     ELSE NULL 
END AS cityjson
FROM test AS m;

Note that it also automagically handles both the removal of the curly braces as well as the exponential notation in your real[]-type value, so you don't need the ::float[] anymore.



cityjson




{    "cityJson": {        "somekey": "someVal"    },    "metadata": {        "scale": [            98.016,            1332612.5,            6717677.5        ],        "translate": [            98.01599884033203,            1332612.5,            6717677.5        ]    }}



ELSE NULL is sometimes added for verbosity, but it's the default behaviour so it can be omitted.

it is the answer to my question! but is there any chance to get rid of the {} in the text?

just saw your update to the answer. AMAZING! Thanks!!
